# c# check if "*" is being repeated in a string

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to count how many * symbols i have in my string. however im getting an error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.dll

I'm simply using a regex match to check it. When i tested with any other string it worked perfectly, but when i search for " * " it get's an exception.

Here's the code that gives expresion

```
string abc = "i am just trying *** for a sample code";
var count = Regex.Matches(abc, "*").Count;
Console.Out.WriteLine(count);
```

This one works perfectly

```
string abc = "i am just trying  for a sample code";
var count = Regex.Matches(abc, "a").Count;
Console.Out.WriteLine(count);
```

Any Idea why ?

Comment: The error message would be helpful.

Comment: *"any idea why"* - yes, the `*` character is a so-called [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) and it therefore must be escaped.

Comment: You should really quote the full details of the exception in your question. In this case I assume the exception message says something like: `parsing "*" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.`

Comment: This is such a duplicate question, but has answers anyway.

Answer (score 11):

You could use LINQ `Count` instead:

```
string abc = "i am just trying *** for a sample code";
var result = abc.Count(c=>c=='*');
```

Comment: In theory this can be improved in some cases (particularly if the string is long and the target characters are near the start) by avoiding counting every single occurrence, and stopping as soon as a duplicate is found: `bool dups = s.SkipWhile(c => c != '*').Skip(1).Any(c => c == '*');`

Answer (score 6):

`*` is a metacharacter and needs to be escaped

```
var count = Regex.Matches(abc, @"\*").Count;
```

Answer (score 2):

`*` has special meaning on a regex, you should escape it with `\`. Try:

```
var count = Regex.Matches(abc, @"\*").Count;
```